# dbinom(x, N, phat) in R returns "NaNs produced". How can I solve this?

Tags: r, binomial-distribution, error-message

Hope I find you well, and happy new year!
I have a little problem with R. I just started using it for university and I'm trying to find the binomial distribution law using the CL column of the crabs table from the MASS library. Here's what I wrote until now:

```
x<-c(crabs$CL)
N<-max(x)
n<-length(x)
xbar<-mean(x)
phat<-xbar/N
pteor<-dbinom(x,N,phat)
```

After trying to executethe last line, im getting the following error message:

> ```
> Warning message:
> In dbinom(x, N, phat) : NaNs produced
> ```

Could you tell me, please, what I did wrong?
Thank you! Have a nice day!

P.S.: This is an assignment we had for university, and I am doing the requirements listed by her step-by-step. Since we have done, and we'll finish this semester online because of COVID-19, the teacher hasn't put in much effort in explaining to us what to do exactly, so what I'm trying to do doesn't make much sense for me either.

The steps are:

1. choose a column,
2. find the N of the binomial law,
3. estimate the parameter p (assuming that the random variable X associated with data follows the following law: Binomial Bi(N, p) with N the value of point 2),
4. make a distribution test for the binomial law,
5. find a 95% confidence region for the parameter p, so the confidence region will be relative to the parameter p.

So far we have:

```
N=47.6
phat=0.6744853
xbar=32.1055
```

Comment: is any of x, N or phat NaN?

Comment: `crabs$CL` does not contain integers so what you're doing does not make much sense.

Comment: We cannot explain what went "wrong" until you describe what you think "right" might be.  Indeed, even when the data `crabs$CL` might consist of integers, this calculation has little meaning--but that doesn't tell us much about what you intended this calculation to do.

Comment: Alright, I added a few more details to explain my confusion a bit better.

Comment: $N$ should have been integer

Comment: The binomial distribution applies to integer data. In the ```crabs``` dataset, you could code the ```sp``` or ```sex``` columns as binary variables (i.e. choose one value to be 1 and the other to be 0), but the other columns are continuous values and so the binomial distribution does not apply. So, your issue may just be the choice of column (or dataset).

Comment: agreeing with everyone else: `CL` is "carapace length". It doesn't make any sense to model it as a binomial distribution

Answer (score 1):

Partially answered in comments:

> Agreeing with everyone else: `CL` is "carapace length". It doesn't
> make any sense to model it as a binomial distribution

- Ben Bolker